# How to hold an iterator inside a struct in rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do this

```rust
struct RwindIter {
    iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>,
}

fn build(i: impl Iterator<Item = String>) -> RwindIter {
    RwindIter { iter: Box::new(i) }
}
```

But I got this error

```
   Compiling myml v0.1.0 (/Users/gecko/code/myml)
error[E0310]: the parameter type `impl Iterator<Item = String>` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:47:23
   |
47 |     RwindIter { iter: Box::new(i) }
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `impl Iterator<Item = String>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:47:23
   |
47 |     RwindIter { iter: Box::new(i) }
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound  `'static` to `impl Iterator<Item = String>`...
   |
46 | fn build(i: impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'static) -> RwindIter {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
error: could not compile `myml`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I was expecting that `Box::new(x)` would take the onwership of `x` so I can't figure out what the error message means. Any ideas?

---

Update

Okay I know it's some limitation around `impl` syntax. This works

```
struct I {}

impl Iterator for I {
    type Item = String;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        None
    }
}

fn build(i: I) -> RwindIter {
    RwindIter { iter: Box::new(i) }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is the iterator references the thing it's iterating, so it can't be saved independently without lifetime information.

Comment: I thought that the iterator would own it's contents, or kind of wraps the ownership of Item until we call next()

Comment: No, it's entirely dependent on the thing it's iterating existing. It doesn't have a copy of the data it's iterating for performance and efficiency reasons, it's just a light-weight structure that tracks position and a smidge of state.

Comment: If the iterator *is* of static lifetime (for e.g. you make one from `Vec<String>` by calling `vec.into_iter()`, then you can add a ` + 'static` bound to the parameter as the rustc suggests.

Comment: Adding a `+ 'static` constraint to your `build` makes it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend just using a regular generic to solve the issue.

```rust
pub struct FooIter<I> {
    iter: I,
}

impl<I> FooIter<I> {
    pub fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        FooIter { iter }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator<Item=String>> Iterator for FooIter<I> {
    type Item = String;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}
```

However you can still use a `dyn Iterator<Item=String>` so long as you provide a lifetime bound. However it could lead to a massive mess of lifetimes later on during implementation depending on how you interact with this struct.

```rust
pub struct FooIter<'a> {
    iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=String> + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> FooIter<'a> {
    pub fn new(iter: impl Iterator<Item=String> + 'a) -> Self {
        FooIter {
            iter: Box::new(iter),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for FooIter<'a> {
    type Item = String;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would `where I: Iterator` help here?

Comment: You could use the `where x: y` syntax if you want to, but I normally reserve it for when the initial generic declaration is getting too long or I need to add additional constraints on trait types. Ex: `impl<I: Iterator> for FooIter where <I as Iterator>::Item: Into<String>`. Generally speaking though, they should be equivalent.

Comment: Hmm, so I don't need that Box there, interesting! Thank you!

Comment: Usually, adding a `'static` instead of a generic `'a` usually makes more sense when you are boxing a value. Because why would you box a value with a non static life time?

Comment: I think the first option is deprecated now? I get error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword when calling new...

Comment: @feature_engineer, this is not deprecated and continues to work fine in rust playground. Unlike languages with inheritance, everything should have a concrete type so we can not use traits interchangeably with type names. So you will not be able to do something like `FooIter<Iterator<Item=String>>` because `Iterator` is a trait, not a type. We can turn some traits into anonymous trait objects like in the second example, but you likely want to use a concrete type instead.