# How do I hold an iterator in struct

Tags: rust, iterator

The existing answer on StackOverflow ([How to hold an iterator inside a struct in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406233/how-to-hold-an-iterator-inside-a-struct-in-rust)) seems to be deprecated (Or I'm missing something)...

When following the proposed solution, I get `error[E0782]: trait objects must include the dyn keyword`, and if I use `dyn` my struct's size isn't known at compile time..

I wonder if I've done something wrong, or if the correct way of doing this has changed...

Here's my initial code:

```
pub struct ChunkIterator<I: Iterator, const N: usize> {
    i: I
}

impl<I: Iterator, const N: usize> ChunkIterator<I, N>  {
    pub fn new(i: I) -> Self {
        assert!(N != 0, "chunk size must be non-zero");
        Self { i }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator, const N: usize> Iterator for ChunkIterator<I, N> {
    type Item = [I::Item; N];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> where Self: Sized {
        let mut arr: Self::Item = [I::Item(); N];
        for i in 1..N {
            arr[i] = self.i.next()?;
        }
        Some(arr)
    }
}
```

I get the error when I try calling new:

```
ChunkIterator::<dyn Iterator<Item=LetterSet>, 3>::new(...my iterator pipline...)...continued pipeline on chunks
```

How do I write this code correctly?

Here's a concrete usage:

```
let d = "Just an example".split(" ");
let s = ChunkIterator::<dyn Iterator<Item=&str>, 3>::new(d).map(|a| a[0]).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
```

I get the following error:

> error[E0599]: the function or associated item `new` exists for struct
> `ChunkIterator<dyn Iterator<Item = &str>, 3>`, but its trait bounds
> were not satisfied   --> src/main.rs:9:58    | 9  |     let s =
> ChunkIterator::<dyn Iterator<Item=&str>, 3>::new(d).map(|a|
> a.max()).collect::<Vec<&str>>();    |
> ^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `ChunkIterator<dyn Iterator<Item = &str>, 3>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds    |   :::
> /home/feature/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:67:1
> | 67 | pub trait Iterator {    | ------------------ doesn't satisfy
> `dyn Iterator<Item = &str>: Sized`    |    = note: the following trait
> bounds were not satisfied:
> `dyn Iterator<Item = &str>: Sized`

If I try calling it without the `dyn` before `Iterator<Item=&str>`, I get `error[E0782]: trait objects must include the dyn keyword`... What am I missing?

Comment: Your code (and the answer) is correct, you're just not calling it correctly. You should not call it with `dyn Iterator`. But to tell exactly what went wrong we need to see more code.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've added an example for how I call it.

Comment: Leave it inferred (`ChunkIterator::<_, 3>`).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks, that moved my error to a different place :)  - I now fail on the line let mut arr = [I::Item(); N]; But I guess this would be a subject for a new question...